# Why do GCC atomic builtins need an additional "generic" version?

Tags: c, gcc, intrinsics, stdatomic

According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html, there's:

```
type __atomic_load_n (type *ptr, int memorder)
```

and (the "generic"):

```
void __atomic_load (type *ptr, type *ret, int memorder)
```

then

```
void __atomic_store_n (type *ptr, type val, int memorder)
```

and ("the generic")

```
void __atomic_store (type *ptr, type *val, int memorder)
```

etc.

What is generic about the latter versions (that's not generic about the former ones) and why are they needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is right in the GCC manual in [section 6.55](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html), which says:

> The ‘__atomic’ builtins can be used with any integral scalar or pointer type that is 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes in length. 16-byte integral types are also allowed if ‘__int128’ (see __int128) is supported by the architecture.
>
> The four non-arithmetic functions (load, store, exchange, and compare_exchange) all have a generic version as well. This generic version works on any data type. It uses the lock-free built-in function if the specific data type size makes that possible; otherwise, an external call is left to be resolved at run time. This external call is the same format with the addition of a ‘size_t’ parameter inserted as the first parameter indicating the size of the object being pointed to. All objects must be the same size.

Comment: It still seems to me like there should be no need to have two versions for this. Sure, with functions, it'd be wise to take big objects by reference, but these are compiler builtins. A compiler should be able to use pointers internally where needed without having to bother users with two APIs.

Comment: @PSkocik *shrug* I'm certain there's some reason behind why they chose not to do that (compiler teams generally have some sort of policy behind why they choose one mechanism over another).  If you're really curious about it, then I'd encourage you to reach out to the gcc community (via their gcc list--see the [mailing lists](https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html) page).  It's been a while since I've interacted with the gcc community, but I've found them pleasant and helpful in the past.